# How to generate household income from couple's individual income

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I need to generate a variable representing household income. I have each individual's income information and have identified the head (`head == 1`) and spouse (`spouse == 1`). Now I decide to define the household income as head's income plus their spouse's income if the head is married or the head's income if unmarried. In this case, I cannot simply use some command like

```
bys hhid : egen hhincome = total(income)
```

because there may be other members in the household who receiveincome, such as adult children  living with their parents. So how can I achieve my goal, either using an `egen` function or other approach?

---

Thanks,Nick,it's really a tactful solution. Another a little bit lumpy solution come to my mind later on : Given I have used bysort prefix to generate the two dummy,head and spouse, the head and his/her spouse should appear as the first two members in each household group,then I can write something like `bys hhid:gen hhincome=sum(income) in 1/2 if（pid==2&spouse==1）`for married head and `bys hhid:gen hhincome=income  if(（pid==2&spouse==.）| hsize==1)`for unmarried head or single-member household,where `pid`stands for individual's id and `hsize`is a previously created dummy for household size

Answer (score 0):

```
bysort hhid : egen hhincome = total(cond(head == 1, income, 0) + cond(spouse == 1, income, 0))
```

or

```
bysort hhid : egen hhincome = total((head == 1) * income + (spouse == 1) * income)
```

Comment: Thanks,Nick,it's really a tactful solution. Another a little bit lumpy solution come to me later on